# View timestamps in human readable format

Tags: timestamped

When I browse my `~.zsh_history` I sometimes wish that the timestamps would be a human readable time format. Is there any mode for emacs that can view the timestamps in a human readable format (just viewing/overlaying, not changing the file).

Sure I can do something like `history -E 0 > hist_tmp; emacs hist_tmp`. But is there a more direct emacs way to do it?

Comment: I don't know what `history -E 0` does, but maybe you can run it in an emacs shell? Do `C-h f shell` for info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`epoch-view` minor mode on Elpa](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/epoch-view.html) *(credits to [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2024-03/msg00066.html))*, which you can install as usual.

It's not very customizable though, so to have a different "face" and format you might have to override a few things. This setup looks good to my taste:

```lisp
(use-package epoch-view
  :defer t
  :config
  (defun epoch-view--render (text)
    "Override `epoch-view--render' to avoid showing non-decoded text"
    (epoch-view--render-time text))

  (defun epoch-view-render ()
    "Override `epoch-view-render' to set a different face"
    (let ((text (match-string-no-properties 0)))
      `(face bold
             display ,(epoch-view--render text))))
  )
```

---

**Older answer**:

Sure, you can define a simple major mode for `zsh_history` files as follows:

```lisp
;;; --- zsh_history highlighting -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(defvar zsh-hist-display-date-format "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z"
  "Date format for displaying the timestamp (see `locale -k date_fmt')")

(defun zsh-hist-convert-unix-timestamp (timestamp)
  (format-time-string zsh-hist-display-date-format
                      (seconds-to-time (string-to-number timestamp))))

(defun zsh-hist-display ()
  `( face bold
     display ,(zsh-hist-convert-unix-timestamp (match-string-no-properties 1))
     zsh-hist:fontified t))

(define-derived-mode zsh-history-mode text-mode "Zsh History Files"
  "Major mode for viewing zsh-history files."
  ;; BUG: this may potentially remove font-lock for other modes that decided to use
  ;; 'display. Unfortunately it is unclear how to make font-lock only remove 'display
  ;; for our mode.
  (setq-local font-lock-extra-managed-props '(zsh-hist:fontified display))
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^: \\([0-9]+\\)" (0 (zsh-hist-display))))))

;;;###autoload
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("zsh_history" . zsh-history-mode))
```

Note: unfortunately Emacs doesn't seem to provide a way to print time with the current locale format *(or maybe I didn't find it, please comment if so)*, so you'll have to replace or customize `zsh-hist-display-date-format` variable manually to set its content to the output of `locale -k date_fmt` command.

Comment: Great thanks. Is there a way to toggle between this view and normal timestamp view? I tried to go back to fundamental mode, but it doesn't change the view back.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point, let me see…

Comment: Well, that's weird. What you usually do in minor modes is you execute a `font-lock-remove-keywords` upon exiting. The `define-minor-mode` allows for code to be executed both when enabling and disabling the mode. However, a major mode it seems like doesn't have such facility :/

Comment: I did find a bug which I fixed: a font-lock has to be bound to a mode. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to fix the problem of switching off the display

Comment: Sorry, I dug through documentation, I tried experimenting, I tried a bunch of things, but it just doesn't work. First of all, I found no documentation that would explain how that supposed to work My gut feeling is that Emacs ought to remove these font-locks automatically upon switching major mode. Because I'd presume that's what "mode" parameter of `font-lock-add-keywords` is for. In reality though Emacs just doesn't do it and I don't know why and again I found no documentation that would point me to anything.

Comment: I partially solved it: there's a `font-lock-extra-managed-props` variable into which a property has to be added to be removed upon exit. But for some reason it only removes `bold` but not the timestamp display. Not sure why is that.

Comment: @student okay, I figured it out, should work now. The code is not ideal but Idk how to make it better. It works though.

Comment: About the bug: I think you need `(make-local-variable 'font-lock-extra-managed-props)` before setting it, and give it an independent value with `setq` before changing it: `(setq font-lock-extra-managed-props (copy-list font-lock-extra-managed-props)) (add-to-list 'font-lock-extra-managed-props …)` or directly `(setq font-lock-extra-managed-props '(zsh-hist:fontified display))`.

Comment: Thanks, but after your update it doesn't seem to do anything. Tried an init file (`test_init.el`) just with your code (and loaded via `emacs -q --load test_init.el`). Calling `M-x zsh-history-mode` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @student yeah, it was due to `font-lock-add-keywords` binding to the mode name explicitly instead of just `nil`. Interestingly, it works fine without `-Q`, only with `-Q` the problem appears. Anyway, the parameter seems to do nothing useful so I replaced it to `nil` rather than trying to figure out what's going on. While at it, please see the updated answer where I mention `epoch-view` mode as an existing alternative.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thank you, good point on local variable! I used a `setq-local` to simplify that. However, you might have misunderstood the meaning of the bug: it's that another mode may have used `'display` to change something and if our mode is disabled, the display-changes of this unrelated mode will get removed as well. Stefan Monnier [says that it as good as it gets ☹](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2024-03/msg00069.html)

Comment: In general I'd be cautious adding `display` to `font-lock-extra-managed-props` as it would cause `font-lock-default-unfontify-region` to mess with *anything* from `C-h i g (elisp)Other Display Specs` regardless of where it came from; but for a `zsh-history-mode` it sounds fairly safe.  If it's a problem, though, then "don't use font-lock" would be my comment -- you'd need to manage the properties using something different, so that you could add/track/remove them without other things interfering.

Comment: Thanks, epoch minor mode seems to work well. Do you know how to search for a human readable timestamp in epoch mode? Using isearch doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @student sorry, I don't know